# What are those translation devices you see at the UN called?

Tags: single-word-requests

What are the devices called that don't create a translation themselves (unlike the infamous LogBar ili or a fictional babelfish), but receive an infrared or radio signal of a human providing a live translation and play it in a connected earphone?

Comment: Can you show pictures? Tried Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Interpretation_Service?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Aren't they just (generic) headphones? They are described as [special / specialized](http://www.translationequipmenthq.com/), but that may refer more to purpose than to the technology.

Comment: Is one in the picture here: http://www.un.org/en/sections/about-un/official-languages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insiders refer to these devices also RF receivers or FM receivers (when working with radio frequency technology) or IR receivers (for infrared). More info can be obtained in [The Beginners Guide to Wireless Interpretation Equipment Rental](http://iprobesolutions.com/learn/the-beginners-guide-to-wireless-interpretation-equipment-rental)

Answer (score 1):

If they receive an infrared or radio signal, the devices are infrared or radio receivers with attached headphones. The whole UN process is described here: http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2009/09/lost_in_translation.html